# need help resetting password MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, passwords, macos-mojave, macos-catalina, forgot-password

Upon downgrading to Mojave from Catalina, my password wouldn't work. This meant I couldn't transfer my backup to my new Mojave OS. I can log in to my user that I've created but when using the same password it won't work when prompted. In an effort to fix this I tried to create a new password through recovery mode (per this article: https://www.macworld.com/article/2868032/what-to-do-if-your-mac-refuses-to-accept-your-password.html) with command R. The trouble is this always goes to network and gives me -1008F as an error before allowing me to reset my password. I then bought a Ethernet adapter (per this forums suggestion: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250788987) for Mac and the same error still pops up. Is there anything I am missing here? What should I do?